# XSLT and Apache FOP

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I have a question about telling XSL the path of where my images are located.
So i have an XML where I add an image like this:

```
<image src="image.png"></image>
```

This is my XSL

```
<fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" src="{@src}">
<xsl:attribute name="src">
<xsl:value-of select="image/@src" />
</xsl:attribute>
</fo:external-graphic>
```

But my picture is in the map Images, but I dont want to add the map in the path of the XML. I want to tell XSL or Apache fop to search for the images map.

Does someone know how to do this

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you mean by "map".

But as it looks, maybe you should rewrite the src attribute from `select="image/@src"` to

`<xsl:value-of select="{concat('image/',@src)}" />`

using attribute substitution and concatenating your fixed string 'image/' with the src attribute from your source xml.

Comment: Hello @stefanhengy By map I mean the folder where the pictures are located

Comment: yes, that's what I assumed, can you try my suggestion from the answer?

Comment: No it doesnt work, 'image/',@src is just to tell where to find the src it still doesnt tell XSL in wich folder the images are

Comment: Where are the images really? Maybe you should specify a parameter for the stylesheet to give the absolute "root" path of the image/ directory and then `select={concat($imagesroot,'/image/',@src)}"` because where from should the processor know where to find the images?

Comment: I can give it a try, the images are in the folder called Image om my local drive now for testing